# How to implement advertising after 5 losses? Unity android

Tags: unity-game-engine

How to implement advertising after 5 losses?

How to implement advertising after 5 losses? Unity Ads. It works, but I need to do that after the player loses five times, an ad is on!

Here is the code that I have!

```c#
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.Advertisements;

public class AdsManager : MonoBehaviour 
{
    private int i = 0;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        if (Advertisement.isSupported)
        Advertisement.Initialize ("23153718", false);
        else
        Debug.Log ("Platform is not supported");
        i = 0;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {     
        if (GameManager.singleton.isGameOver == true)
        {  
            if (i == 0)
            {
                ShowAd();
                i++;
            }  
        }
    }

    public void ShowAd()
    {
        if (Advertisement.IsReady())
        {
             Advertisement.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see you increment i anywhere besides after checking whether it equals 0. This code only shows an ad once and cannot show any other ad since i never reaches 0 again. What have you tried so far ?

Comment: Hold a counter in `GameManager.singleton`, increament it every time game is over. Check here if it is 5 show the add then make counter zero.

Comment: @Jon can you show us how you know a player has lost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have mutliple Scenes you could simply use `static` for that value since it is a single value that counts for the entire app (thus it doesn't depend on instances).

With a proper setter method there is also no need to check the counter every frame in `Update` but only when it is actually changed.

If you than replace also the `Start` method with a [`static` constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-constructors) you could make the entire class `static` and it wouldn't need to be a `MonoBehaviour` at all.

```c#
public static class AdsManager
{
    private static bool _isSuppoerted;

    public static int AdsCounter
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public static void IncreaseAdsCounter()
    {
        AdsCounter++;

        if (AdsCounter >= 5)
        {
            ShowAd();
            AdsCounter = 0;
        }
    }

    public static void ShowAd()
    {
        if(!_isSuppoerted) 
        {
            Debug.LogWarning("AdsManager: Platform is not supported!");
            return;
        }

        if (Advertisement.IsReady())
        {
            Advertisement.Show();
        }

        // maybe reset the counter also if called from somewhere else?
        //AdsCounter = 0;
    }

    // Use this for initialization
    static AdsManager()
    {
        if (Advertisement.isSupported)
        {
            Advertisement.Initialize("23153718", false);
            _isSuppoerted = true;
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogWarning("AdsManager: Platform is not supported!");
            _isSuppoerted = false;
        }

        AdsCounter = 0;
    }
}
```

Than from any other script e.g. within `GameManager` you can simply call

```c#
AdsManager.IncreaseAdsCounter();
```

Comment: if (GameManager.singleton.isGameOver == true) I use as an indicator of the fact that the player lost!

Comment: well, where do you set it to `true`? as said instead/additionally simply call `AdsManager.IncreaseAdsCounter();`

Comment: Thank you! It all worked! I have not deleted the extra lines from the last attempt!